# Emacs Live linum-mode messed up when switching buffers

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs Live (https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) and I have global linum-mode enabled. However when I switch from a buffer to another, and then back to the original buffer, the line numbers are all messed up like so. Thanks. [image]

Comment: If you disable the Emacs Live package and use just a regular version of Emacs, does that fix the problem?  If so, then you should open an issue on Github with the Emacs Live package developer.  If disabling the Emacs Live package doesn't solve the issue, then your next step is to launch Emacs with a blank `.emacs` file to see if it works correctly with nothing installed and no user configuration except for global line numbers.  If it works correctly at that point, then you'll need to start by commenting out portions of your `.emacs` file to track down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before digging further into it, you may want to try out `nlinum-mode` (available from GNU ELPA), which provides similar functionality, but using an implementation technique that tends to be more reliable.